# is it possible to remote debugging java program in kubernetes using ingress?

Tags: java, kubernetes, debugging, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We deployed several java application in kubernetes.when i try connect with NodePort i can connect without problem. i want to conenct each of them debug port using  ingress faced this issue :
`Unable to open debugger port (test-java.next.com:80): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - unrecognized message from target VM"`
my ingress configuration is here

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: "debug-svc"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "128k"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffers: "4 256k"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-header-buffer-size: "16k"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
  labels:
    app: debug
  name: debug-ing
  namespace: emas
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-test
  rules:
  - host: test-java.next.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: debug-svc
            port:
              number: 10090
```

ingress logs here :
 `- - [19/Dec/2023:16:23:18 +0400] "JDWP-Handshake" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.003 [] [] - - - - a2098508e9c86bc32542f64da5a7cbfb`

i tried several type of configuration of ingress resource.

Comment: I didn't try it my self but as you're using nginx this may be able to help you: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

On the other hand, If you can avoid the ingress part and you can access the kubectl there's a good guide here: https://refactorfirst.com/how-to-remote-debug-java-application-on-kubernetes

Hope it helps.